# Exporting images in an image collection from GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Please I would like to know the best way to export image bands from an Image Collection in Google Earth Engine for use on my local machine. The image collection contains 21 elements which I would like to export as single image bands or an image composite of all 21 elements. How do I go about this please. Below is a code extract I have written. Thanks

```
var S1_1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(SA)
  .filterDate('2016-10-01', '2017-06-01')
  .filterMetadata('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'equals', ['VV', 'VH'])
.filterMetadata('resolution_meters', 'equals' , 10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295705/image-collection-to-single-image-in-google-earth-engine/295978#295978) which shows you how to turn an image collection into a single band image.  From there, use `Export.image.toDrive()`.